# System.TypeLoadException in example from MSDN

Tags: c#, monodevelop, linux-mint

I have an error while build one example from MSDN (here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=netframework-4.8).

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000e from typeref (expected class 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng' in assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
```

I'm using MonoDevelop (ver. 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) on LinuxMint 19.1 Tessa.

Comment: Looks like your missing an assembly...

Comment: I have installed MonoDevelop today, on clear system, I did not add any packages to this IDE. I don't quite understand what kind of assembly you talk about.

Comment: Try Solution->Packages->Edit Packages...this is how you add references. Most IDE out of the box will not have everything under the sun to call or reference. You have to add them.